# Drupal 7 Services: if non-empty field json is object, if same field is empty json is empty array

Tags: json, service, drupal, drupal-7, gson

I am using Drupal Services and I've noticed that fields with empty values are being always displayed in my JSON as an empty array.

For example:
A non-empty field (It is an object in my json):

```
"field_example": {
  "und": [
    {
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
},
```

Same field. Empty in this case (It is an emtpy array in my json):

```
"field_example": [
],
```

This can be frustrating when consumers of the service are expecting, for instance, an object but gets an array (Using Gson for example).

What is the best way to face that?